# FullCalendar multiple events

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

Im having a bit of a headache :) - Im trying to add multiple event to a calender, which ALMOST works as it should. When adding a new event, the event gets created and rendered to the calendar. Then when adding the second event and saving, it creates 2 new events, when it only should create one (the new event) - Any ideas?

When creating a new event I just pass in a new object:

```
newEvent.title = title;
     newEvent.start = started;
     newEvent.end = end,
       newEvent.allDay = false;

     if (title) {
       calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent', newEvent, true);
     }

     calendar.fullCalendar('unselect');
```

See a work in progress fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/7bo7z3d0/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .antosubmit on click handler is getting another copy added each time you do a selection. One (probably not the best) way to stop it is

```
$(".antosubmit").on("click", function() {
    ...
    $('.antoclose').click();
    $(this).off('click'); /* <--- Turn off the click handler! */
    return false;
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7bo7z3d0/2/